# Using SharePoint WSS_Content database to find permissions changes?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, sql-server, content-database, auditing

I've noticed there are a few tables that may be able to help me put together an "Audit Log" of sorts for permissions changes in our SharePoint site.  However, I'm unsure of how to join up the tables to make sense of what permissions changes actually took place, when, and by whom.

Does anyone have any experience using the SharePoint WSS_Content database to put together readable event/audit logs?

For example:  The other day, somehow every user's permissions that begin with "A" were removed from our site collection, leading to a rather large problem with user access.  I need to find out what kind of site permissions changed and by who.  I have access to the WSS_Content database and thought this might be a good location to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't be supported. Instead, enable Site Collection auditing in the target Site Collection(s). While there is an explicit 'permissions' audit setting, you may also want the Edit Items audit setting as that will capture changes to SharePoint Groups.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor.  Am I correct in assuming that this historical data is lost since the auditing wasn't configured in the first place?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.